# Free standalone crawlers

Tags: web-crawlers, crawl-errors

Are there any free standalone crawlers that I can use apart from Google webmaster to analyze errors?

Something that shows me all 404's, errors etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) is what  you're probably looking for

Answer (score 1):

Another crawling tool which is free for upto 500 urls is [Screaming Frog SEO Spider](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, try [Integrity](http://peacockmedia.co.uk/integrity/), which is free and works great.